# problem in executing selenium standalone jar

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am beginner in Java selenium, i have problem in executing selenium standalone jar I am using
eclipse version 4.15, JDk 14.0, selenium 3.14

**error got**
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Java-selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar

```
package SeleniumPractice;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;//error importing org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver not accessible

public class launchBrowser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //launch chrome browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./driver/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();//Error: cannot b resolved
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are importing a JAR package, then the folder containing the `.jar` file has to be included in the [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) of your project. [In this thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1101004/) you can find instructions for setting a project classpath in Eclipse.

You should also consider using a package manager for managing dependencies, for example [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). Eclipse provides great support for Maven, you can find details [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html). It is Ubuntu tutorial while you are probably using Windows, but everything important is the same here.

If you'll have any additional questions, comment this answer and I'll edit it accordingly.

---

In case you wanted to try Maven, I've attached an example of a `pom.xml` file - configuration file for Maven projects - that I use for running Selenuim tests. To run the tests using this setup, you need to go to the folder with the `pom.xml` file. In this folder run command `mvn clean test`

Before using the file, replace or remove:

- `com.example.your.domain` as groupId
- `your-app-name` as artifactId,
- the `<repositories>` section (since I use a private repo for a few things)
- anything that doesn't fit you - notice that Java version is set to `1.8` and Selenium is managed by TestNG framework, which is executed by [Surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html), you don't need this setup.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.your.domain</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-app-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>reporter</name>
                            <value>listenReport.Reporter</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

<!--    <repositories>
        <repository>
            You might have to add a custom repo.
        </repository>
    </repositories>-->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```